# Парсер Email

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Попытался сделать парсер Email, который бы бродил по сайтам которых он же и находил. 
Вышло что то вот такое(Где то я на косячил):

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect ('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('Pars',$db);
mysql_query('SET NAMES cp1251',$db);          
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET cp1251',$db);  
mysql_query('SET COLLATION_CONNECTION="cp1251_general_ci"',$db);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Url`",$db) or die(mysql_error());
while($show = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Urllist (url) VALUES('". mysql_real_escape_string($show['url'])."')"); 
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Url` WHERE url = '".$show['url']."'");
$get =  @file_get_contents($show['url']);
preg_match_all('/href="(.*?)"/',$get,$matches2);
preg_match_all("/href='(.*?)'/",$get,$matches);
$matches = array_merge($matches[1], $matches2[1]);
preg_match_all('/[\.\-_A-Za-z0-9]+?@[\.\-A-Za-z0-9]+
?[\.A-Za-z0-9]{2,}/', $get, $out);
foreach ( $out as $okey ) {
$rsurl = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Email` WHERE email='$okey'",$db) or die(mysql_error());
$ururl = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsurl);
if(empty($ururl['id'])){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Email (email) VALUES('". mysql_real_escape_string($okey)."')"); 
}
}
foreach ( $matches as $key ) {
$surl = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Url` WHERE url='$key'",$db) or die(mysql_error());
$rurl = mysql_fetch_assoc($surl);
if(empty($rurl['id'])){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Url (url) VALUES('". mysql_real_escape_string($key)."')"); 
}
}
}
?>
```

Ещё и ошибку на 21 строке пишет

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Email (email) VALUES('". mysql_real_escape_string($okey)."')");
```

Ошибка

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in O:\home\test1.ru\www\pars.php on line 21
```

Comment: =( [](http://hashcode.ru/users/12895/netsperes)

Comment: я знаю где вы накосячили: забыли расставить отступы, забыли сказать что парсер вы не писали т.к. не можете разобратся в коде. Почему вы не стараетесь учить программирование а выдаете желаемое за дейстивтельное?

Comment: Во 1 парсер писал я. Да согласен некоторый код не мой мне подсказали здесь: [Парсер ссылок](http://hashcode.ru/questions/231871/php-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA). Если вы не знаете то (извините меня), как там говориться НЕ ЛЕЗЬТЕ со своими придирками.

Comment: :) Согласен войну начинать думаю не стоит. На счет того, что работа ваша, я пожалуй соглашусь. Просто если хотите делать ее хорошо то учитесь расставлять отступы и комментарии между значущими блоками. Вам же проще будет понять, что, где и почему. В общем не обижайтесь.

Comment: Пожалуй ? Это ваша королевская подачка в мою сторону?   Я как хочу так и пишу код.

Comment: вы его пишите очень неправильно и неотимально.
1. mysql_query... - забудте есть PDO
2. для поиска ссылок рабоать лучше не с preg_match есть парсеры.
3. Вы не готовы к разработке даже самых простых проектов.

Думаю на этом трата на вас времени у меня закончилась никому тут ваше "писательство" не поможет. И вы тоже в очень скором времени упретесь в непробиваемую стену.

Comment: А вас ни кто не заставляет тратить на меня время.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В ошибке все уже написано. В переменной `$okey` лежит массив. [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) помещает двумерный массив в параметр **matches** (в вашем случае это переменная `$out`).

Этот код

```
foreach ( $out as $okey ) {
  // ...    
}
```

следует заменить на

```
foreach ( $out[0] as $okey ) {
  // ...    
}
```